# IOS: animage change in bounds of rectangle holding tableview

Tags: ios, animation, tableview

I have a `tableview` that I move up or down depending on the presence of a search bar.  The movement is jerky,as it stands, and I would like to animate it if possible.  Can anyone suggest how to animate a change in bounds? Here is the code that moves the table view

```
CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
   newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y - self.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
   self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code to animate your bound changes, let me know if this resolve your issue.

```
 CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
            delay: 0.0
            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
            animations:^{
               newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y - self.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
       self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;

            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                // do something after animation finishes. 

            }];
```

Comment: That gave me the animation.  Still fussing with how to make it look best but this is the way to do it  Thanks!

Comment: this the way, now you can explore it, you will learn in this way, dont forget to vote up.